# Typescript complains about variable types after array destructuring

Tags: typescript

I have a function

```
function foo() {
    return ["", 1, () => ""];
}
```

types are: `string`, `number` and `(() => string)`

however after I destructure those values

```
const [str, num, func] = foo();
```

compiler treats each variable as type: `string | number | (() => string)`

I want to pass these variables in functions, but compiler complains that types don't match and my IDE goes nuts with red text underlying. What can I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Specify the return type of the function

```
function foo(): [string, number, () => string] {
    return ["", 1, () => ""];
}
```

This will strictly type the function to return an array with:

- value of index 0 to be type `string`
- value of index 1 to be type `number`
- value of index 2 to be type `() => string` / function that returns string

```
function foo(): [string, number, () => string] {
    return [0, 1, () => ""]; // Will shows error because index 0 is number, not string
}
```

Comment: That was simple. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm guessing this is because TS infers the return type to by an array of `any`? or `unknown`? How does TS infer types in this situation?

Comment: When you are returning an array from a function, Typescript will automatically set the return type as all of the possible type inside the returned array, that's why @MatasLiu get `string | number | (() => string)` for each of the returned array value type like explained on @Curtis Fenner's answer, and not `any` or `unknown`. If you want to strictly type it like `"index 0 is string, index 1 is number, index 2 is function"`, you need to declare the return type like I did on my answer.

Comment: Your alternative is not safe and `as` is a dangerous operation, I would suggest, it would be good if you remove alternative ;)

Answer (score 6):

Another way to achieve this is:

```js
function foo() {
  return ['', 1, () => ''] as const
}

const [str, num, func] = foo()
```

Main difference with `as const` and without it is that:

- `as const` tells ts that it is immutable value, hence ts infers concrete type which in this case is tuple of 3, and as you know, tuple can have different types
- without `as const`, ts infers it as `Array` and array takes single type parameter, but in this case array is holding string, number and func values. Hence ts infers it as `(string | number | () -> string)[]`

Comment: This is definitely more elegant!

Answer (score 5):

By default, TypeScript infers the type of an array literal not as a tuple, but as an array of a union of all of the element types. So in `const x = [a, b, c];` isn't inferred to have type `[A, B, C]` but instead `(A | B | C)[]`.

If you want TypeScript to infer a tuple type, you have to explicitly indicate that:

```
const x: [A, B, C] = [a, b, c]; // this typechecks
```

An alternative is to use the `as const` syntax:

```
const x = [a, b, c] as const; // infers as `readonly [A, B, C]`
```

This isn't the only place where TypeScript infers a less-specific type than seems possible. For example, string literals by default infer as `string` instead of their literal type: `let x = "word"; // string` vs `let x = "word" as const; // "word"` vs `const x = "word"; // "word"`